# How to find the optimal solution for Reve's puzzle?

Tags: optimization, puzzle

I recently had a homework about [tower of hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) that ended a derivative of four pegs, called Reve's puzzle.

The [Stewart algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Frame.E2.80.93Stewart_algorithm) seems to be the optimal solution to solve it with the least moves number possible, cutting the initial tower in two intermediate ones of `k` and `n - k` sizes, with `n` the number of disks to move and `k` an integer between `1` and `n - 1`.

I understood how to explain this algorithm, except on one point: the optimal `k` choice appears to be [image: optimal k choice], rounded minus 1.

Why is it the optimal solution?

Comment: It *seems* to be the optimal solution, but it has not yet been proven that it *is* the optimal solution.  This is still an open problem to my knowledge.

Comment: @JMoravitz It is still an open problem because nobody proved that [Stewart algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Frame.E2.80.93Stewart_algorithm) was the most optimal solution, but it may be an explanation on why, for this precise algorithm, the optimal k is given my this formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is *no longer an open problem*, even at the time of the OP. The Frame-Stewart bound was proved optimal by Thierry Bousch in *[La quatrième tour de Hanoï](http://topo.math.u-psud.fr/~bousch/preprints/revespzl.pdf)* which appeared in the *Bulletin of the Belgian Mathematical Society - Simon Stevin* in 2014.

Answer (score 0):

According to [A007664](http://oeis.org/A007664) the Stewart algorithm has been proven optimal for $n \le 30$.  One implementation is at [The Reve's Puzzle](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheRevesPuzzle/).

Whether it is optimal for 31 disks, 32 disks, and so on is still an open problem.